# The different behaviour in Local and AWS postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

The to_tsquery() function of postgresql behaves diffrently in local and AWS instances,
ex : SELECT column FROM table WHERE column @@ to_tsquery('sometext');
do we need any additional set up to run to_tsquery() in AWS.

Comment: to_tsquery with only one argument depends on the setting of default_text_search_config parameter.  If that parameter is different, you will get different results.

Comment: The result is differe in my local  instance and in aws instance. @jjanes

Comment: Yes, I know.  Is the setting of default_text_search_config different?

Comment: sorry , but where to check this default_text_search_config?.. I just tred to execute that query in pg admin.

Comment: You can just send the "SHOW  default_text_search_config;" SQL command and it should returning the current setting.  (There are also other ways to check)

Comment: @jjanes yeah the default serach config setting is different in my local and AWS.

Comment: I changed default using SET default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english' in my code and after that it worked. @jjanes Thanks for your help and suggestion.